# What is the most efficient method using Request.UserLanguages to render a page based on the browser language??

Tags: string, performance, for-loop, multilingual

I am making a page which pulls from the user's browser their preferred language, via the Request.UserLanguages....which returns a two letter code (ex. "en") or detailed code (ex. "en-GB") .

I basically get the string of user languages (they are in order of preference) and store them in a string array. Then I use a loop to check if the language code in the first position of the string array is any of the codes for a certain language (another string array hard coded in).

Is there a better way to do this? I'm noticing increased load time and am worried additional languages will further slow the page load...

```
 if (!IsPostBack)

    {   //Holds possible user languages preferences to check client machine against
        String[] compJapaneseLang = { "ja-jp","ja","jp","jpn","euc","shift-jis" };
    }

 //Get client machines langugage preferences                
        String[] userLang = Request.UserLanguages;

//Loop through variation of preferences from possible user langugaes

        for (int i = 0; i < compJapaneseLang.Length; i++)
        { 
                //IF JAPANESE
            if (userLang.GetValue(0).ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Equals(compJapaneseLang.GetValue(i).ToString().ToLowerInvariant()))


                cc.JapeneseObject();
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing them in a list turned out best, not really much else one can do....